# ImageButton elevation issue

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, elevation

Good afternoon, I am trying to create en ImageButton with a shadow.

To do that :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5sp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_little"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
        android:elevation="3sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But here is the result :

[image]

As you can see, the borders are "cut", and I do not know why.

Does anyone can help me ? Thank you.

Comment: try changing all `sp` to `dp`

Comment: Didn't work, thanks anyway!

Comment: @D.Math Try adding this line `android:outlineProvider="bounds"`.

Comment: Probably du to your src that was to much big for space available, you should try something like scaleType => fitCenter

Comment: Nope, did'nt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `layout_margin` to your `ImageButton`. The `elevation` shadow gets clipped to the margins of the `View` (which defaults to zero):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_little"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"/>
```

Alternatively, you could set the `padding` of the view and set `clipToPadding="false"`, but this could lead to unexpected results depending on your layout.

Lastly, you [should be](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) using `dp` for everything but `textSize`, in which case you would use `sp`.

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you!