# Android button elevation shadow not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-elevation

I am trying to make a button that has a shadow using elevation with a background image being my sign in with gmail png. The button is contained within a relative layout. The elevation won't show no matter what I try to do. I tried solutions from other forum questions and none worked.

Here is my code for the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/google"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/google"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/slogan"/>
```

The google drawable is a png image that I exported from Adobe XD.
Could someone please give me a pointer on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**Additionally**, I realize that if I set the background of the button to android:color/white the shadow appears. So I think the issue is with the png drawable? Does elevation not work with png images? Is there a workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button

Comment: you can set android:stateListAnimator="@null" for button

Comment: elevation is only used in API level 21 and higher

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya As I said, I already looked through the forums. Setting stateListAnimator to null for the button and clipToPadding to false for the layout still doesn't make the shadow appear. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I ran my emulator at API level 25. I also set the minimum API level in gradle to 21.

Comment: add in cardview and give a elevation to cardview.

Comment: @Jeffrey Chou Background covers elevation view as well. That's why.

Comment: @kevanaghera I tried your workaround and it works. Thanks. But, I am wondering if that is the only workaround or the easiest. It is a hassle to put each button in a card view.

Comment: @NitinPatel So besides putting each button in a cardview, how would I work around that?

Comment: Try this link if it works:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38724984/7806873

Comment: use `android:outlineProvider="bounds"`

Comment: Damn it, I assumed in Android Studio in 2021 I won't have such issues :((

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use below the line of code to show an elevation in button

`android:outlineProvider="bounds"` – K. Sopheak

That works, thanks!

Comment: For me this one resulted in strange background behaviour but  android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds" was the key.

Comment: for me it works only with: elevation, translationZ, outlineProvider=bounds, stateListAnimator=@null

Answer (score 3):

For Material Button, I tried the following and it worked

```
android:translationZ="5dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this I hope it helps, because another view or layout just after your button is hiding shadow

```
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
```

Comment: When I set the background to android:color/white, the shadow appears, so I don't think it is because of another view hiding it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an image, replace the `<Button>` tag with that of an `<ImageButton>`. So, your workaround code would be:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/google"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/google"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/slogan"/>
```

Take note that the `android:src` attribute is being used here rather than the `android:background` attribute.

This one worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

try this , I hope this help you ||

```
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```