# How to add elevation to ImageButton?

Tags: java, android

I added an ImageButton and set it background to imagedrawable but when i add elevation to it I get a rectangular shadow.

**here is my button:**

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bookmark_red"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/bm"
        android:elevation="6dp"/>
```

**Here is the drawable i used :**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722902/imagebutton-elevation-issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to draw your drawable as a svg symbol.

Is your drawable a .jpg? JPG does not support transparent backgrounds and sure, the shadow will be rectangular, because a JPG is always rectangular.

It may will work with a PNG file which has a transparent background (take care, that the background is transparent, not white), but i did not test it.

But with a svg drawable it will work! Maybe the symbol library from Android Studio has a symbol that fits you needs.

Comment: thanks for the answer i didn't notice .